# How to compute the Second and higher order Betti numbers of a graph?

Tags: algebraic-topology, algebraic-graph-theory, betti-numbers

I know that the zeroth Betti number is the number of connected components of a graph, and the first one is computed using Euler characteristics. However, I am not sure if we can compute the higher order Betti numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The nth Betti number is the rank of the nth homology of your graph. Using cellular homology, the Betti numbers of any graph are 0 if $n>1$.